# Is it a good idea to reinstall OS X to attempt to fix some minor issues?

Tags: install

I am having a couple of problems with my Mac (wifi doesn't connect automatically, and audio jack doesn't work unless I restart).

Having failed at fixing them for a while, I am wondering if **reinstalling** the OS (Mavericks) *might* help in such a scenario and should be given a try? (Obviously, I want to reinstall while keeping all my data, settings, apps etc intact.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a variety of strange software problems can be fixed by reinstalling OS X. Providing the installer detects an existing install (which will only not happen if the disk can't boot) your files and settings will be preserved. If you've made any changes to the system such as modifying a keyboard layout or changing the boot logo, you will need to back these up as they will be wiped.

Comment: What do you mean by the last line? What type of changes? I only care that my apps, software settings, files remain intact.

Comment: @Himanshu For example, if you've modified a keyboard layout, or changed the boot logo, these are not kept when you reinstall.

Comment: If I had made any "changes to the system" as you call them, how would I back them up before starting reinstallation?

Comment: @Himanshu Just copy the files manually to somewhere in your home folder or an external disk.

Comment: Ahhh, got it. So you're talking about files that are part of the OS X installation and will be overwritten by the reinstallation process. I take it that apart from those, no other files will be deleted/modified, right?

Comment: @Himanshu Yes, the installer will overwrite anything in its way. Your home folder should be intact, along with your own apps in /Applications. None of your files *should* be modified, but it's always a good idea to have a backup in case the install process is interrupted, etc